# What does the "+|" sign before a folder name on Pycharm mean?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have these non-empty folders, which I can easily browse through the Windows file explorer (as if they were regular folders). They also appear in the project view on Pycharm, but here they are marked with a `+|` (small upper plus sign and a pipe) sign as seen in the snapshot (next to folders data3, data4, data5, data6). However, Python can't access them ("The system cannot find the path specified"). What does this mean? And why can't I access them with Python? (I get this error both in the Pycharm Python console and in Jupyter Notebook - but this symbol does not appear in Jupyter Notebook)

I will add that these folders (as data1 and data2, which are perfectly accessible) are the result of a recent "merge pull request" in Github.

Initially I thought this might be a OneDrive fault but I ruled that out once I copied the entire `go` folder out to a local location and the problem persisted.

[image: plus sign and vertical line before folder name in Pycharm]

Code:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.listdir("D:\\OneDrive - Technion\\SPIRAL\\templates\\go\\data1\\")
['1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '2', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '3', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '4', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '5', '50', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> os.listdir("D:\\OneDrive - Technion\\SPIRAL\\templates\\go\\data3\\")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\OneDrive - Technion\\SPIRAL\\templates\\go\\data3\\'
```

Comment: [Discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250807/discussion-between-whatsthepoint-and-hbi).

Answer (score 0):

From an extended discussion:

This `+|` icon is not one of the [listed pycharm icons](https://jetbrains.design/intellij/resources/icons_list/) on the intelliJ website so it is more than likely a different icon not being shown properly.

Listing the fullnames of folders shows some unicode text in front of your folder names (`\u200f`) which upon some googling is a [`right-to-left` mark](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgraphemica.com%2F200F%2Fglyphs%2Ftimes-new-roman-regular&psig=AOvVaw05gSc4W5bLoAAfgvJF8f0W&ust=1672825308172000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CA8QjRxqFwoTCKimkoOOq_wCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE). Which confirms the theory of the `+|` being in place of a different icon.

As to why/how this unicode character got there I don't know, but renaming this folder to remove this text will fix the problem of not being able to access the folder from your code.